# "Put/value above" vs. "put/value over"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> - The company puts profits **above/over** safety.
> - The company values profits **above/over** safety.

Is it *above* or *over*?

Answer (score 2):

Either can be used. Your choice should be guided by a subtle sensitivity to the connotations of the verb. Hence, I would use "above" with a verb such as "put" or "place" (these have some implication of a physical location), and "over" with a verb such as "value" (which suggests comparative quality or importance).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/american/To-value-something-or-someone

There you can see **put someone/something before/over/above** section with its *definition*:

> to consider someone or something as being more important than someone or something else

Both *over* and *above* are to be used in context of evaluation

Answer (score 0):

I think above is better:
The company puts (remember to add the "s" to put) profits above safety.

I am more concerned about the "Put" I think that can be replaced by 'places':
The company places profits above safety.

Comment: *Put* is grammatical. It just makes it past tense. *Why did the company fail? It put profits above safety and got sued.*

Answer (score -3):

*Above* and *over* can have different meanings in different contexts.

When we value something, we do so using *above*. But if we view something or scenario, we do so *over*.

So in this case I think the choice between *above* and *over* depends on the context in which the company does so.